# html5 cache office document with manifest

Tags: html, caching, ms-office, manifest

I'm trying to use the html5 cache to store locally office documents.
I use :

- ASP.NET MVC 4 on server side
- Chrome / PC and Android Browser / Galaxy Tab (Android 3.1) on client side.

Here is my (test) page (the one I was working on is a little bit complex) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="/HandlerManifest.ashx">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>TestCache</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="/Data/test1.jpg">test1.jpg</a>
<a href="/Data/test.docx">test.docx</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my manifest :

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# v1.0.2.0 du 15/10/2012 14:57:58
CACHE:
/Data/test1.jpg
/Data/test.docx
```

This works fine on Chrome/Pc.
On the Galaxy Tab, I can access the jpg file, even when I m disconnected.
But when I access the docx, connected or disconnected, I have the folowing error : 
Web Page not available

When I remove the manifest, everything works fine.

Do you know if I can only store some kind of files (images, css, js) on Android Web Browser ? Or if there is something wrong with what I'm doing ?

Comment: Just a thought... is your docx filename actually lowercase? Your IIS webserver isn't case sensitive, but the cached files on the Android OS likely are.

Comment: I put everything in lowercase, folder and files, it was a good idea, but that doesn't change anything.